# Tabularx and multicolumn

Tags: tables

When I try to use multicolumn inside a `tabularx` environment, I get this weird behaviour; where the column doesn't fill the whole width.

Anyone know why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}

    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{\sffamily Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,}\\\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|X|}{\lipsum[2]}\\\hline

    \sffamily Lorem av:&\sffamily Ipsum:\\
    foo&bar\\\hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabularx with multicolumn]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to specify `\hsize` like `|>{\hsize=2\hsize}X|`. If it is for three columns `3\hsize` and so on. To be precise, take the `\tabcolsep` and one `\arrayrulewidth` in to account like

```
>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}

    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{\sffamily Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, }\\\hline
  \rowcolor{blue!40}
    \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{\lipsum*[2]}\\\hline

    \sffamily Lorem av:&\sffamily Ipsum:\\
    foo&bar \\\hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As an example, for three columns you have to use

```
>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
```

as in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}

    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{\sffamily Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, }\\\hline
  \rowcolor{blue!40}
    \multicolumn{3}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}{\lipsum*[2]}\\\hline

    \sffamily Lorem av:&\sffamily Ipsum:&\sffamily Ipsum:\\
    foo&bar &bar\\\hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Here there are three columns, six `\tabcolsep`s and 4 `\arrayrulewidth`s. Of these 2 outer `\tabcolsep`s and 2 outer `\arrayrulewidth`s are retained (inside multi column) while the space for 4 `\tabcolsep`s and 2 `\arrayrulewidth`s have to be used.

Comment: Now when I try to add `\rowcolor`, it won't fit the whole column. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}X|}{...}` or you have too short lines.

Comment: @egreg I was editing. Thank you. :-)

Comment: @DavidKristiansen Please see the update.

Comment: I tried to make a custom column type with `\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize+#1\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}` I see It's more going on than I thought.

Thanks, I can work from here!

Comment: @DavidKristiansen Good :-) A note about `\arrayrulewidth`. If you have n multi columns, then you have n+1 rules. You have to subtract all the rule widths except for the left most and right most ones.

Answer (score 5):

I built on top of the accepted answer and made a `\newcommand` for myself to restore easy multicolumns

```
\newcommand{\tabularxmulticolumncentered}[3] 
    {\multicolumn{#1}
                 {>{\centering\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize+#1\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}#2}
                 {#3}}
```

Use as

```
\tabularxmulticolumncentered{2}{X}{My text spanning two columns}
```

Comment: Great contribution ! But I used a 12 column table and it looks a bit cropped so I used this expression `{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize+\tabcolsep * (2 * (#1 - 1) )+\arrayrulewidth* (#1 - 2)\relax}#2|}`

Answer (score 4):

Harish Kumar has already given an answer about the specific problem. Here I'd like to show a different way for inputting what seems to be some kind of form.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{expl3,environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{Form}[1]
 {
  \keys_set:nn { david/form } { #1 }
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}
   {
    |
    p{ \dim_eval:n { .5\textwidth - 2\tabcolsep } }
    |
    p{ \dim_eval:n { .5\textwidth - 2\tabcolsep } }
    |
   }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}
   { | p{ \dim_eval:n { \textwidth - 2\tabcolsep } } | }
   { \sffamily \l_david_form_title_tl }
  \\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}
   { | p{ \dim_eval:n { \textwidth - 2\tabcolsep } } | }
   { \BODY }
  \\
  \hline
  \sffamily Lorem av: & \sffamily Ipsum \\ % <--------- CHANGE HERE
  \l_david_form_bottomleft_tl & \l_david_form_bottomright_tl
  \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
 }

\keys_define:nn { david/form }
 {% CHANGE THE KEY NAMES!
  title .tl_set:N = \l_david_form_title_tl,
  loremav .tl_set:N = \l_david_form_bottomleft_tl,
  ipsum .tl_set:N = \l_david_form_bottomright_tl,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}{
  title = {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu vel enim virtute, modo rebum},
  loremav = foo,
  ipsum = bar
}
Here goes the body of the form, \lipsum*[2]
\end{Form}

\end{document}
```

I used `expl3` for defining the keys and `environ` for gathering the main body. The definitions are longer, but inputting the form is much easier, because the various parts have well definite places and are not hidden in code.

[image]

Comment: It's just a MWE of a larger form I'm making. You can see the whole thing here [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235984/macro-with-19-arguments).
Your code looks greek to me. I'm guessing this is LaTeX3, and something I will have to learn eventually. Might as well dive into it.

Comment: @DavidKristiansen I suspected something like that. In that case you just need 19 keys and make a tabular from them. Maybe you can change that question asking how to fill and print the form with a key-value interface; the mention to the 19 arguments can stay, just ask for a different method. When you have edited it, I'll vote for reopening.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to go, with some improvements (vertical padding of rows):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,array, lipsum}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|S{X}|S{X}|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize- + 2\tabcolsep\relax}S{X}|}{\sffamily Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,}\\
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize + 2\tabcolsep\relax} S{X}|} {\lipsum[2]} \\
  \hline
  \textsf{Lorem av}:\newline foo & \textsf{Ipsum:}\newline bar \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hspan=minimal` with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {|X|X|},
  row{1,3} = {font=\sffamily},
  cell{1,2}{1} = {c=2}{l}, % multicolumn
  hspan = minimal,
}
\hline
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & \\
\hline
  \lipsum[2] & \\
\hline
  Lorem: & Ipsum: \\
  Foo & Bar\\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]