# How to add a newcolumntype for a multicolumn of type X?

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

I want to create a newcolumntype for use inside of a multicolumn.
I tried to implement a new column type with the solution of [Tabularx and multicolumn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236155/tabularx-and-multicolumn).

I added this MWE for more understanding

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    %\newcolumntype{MultiX}[1]{>{\hsize=\dimexpr#1\hsize+((2*#1)-2)\tabcolsep+(#1+1-2)\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}
    %\newcolumntype{TwoX}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Example}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXX}       
            Name & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}{Test} \\
            Target & \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}{ I am a very interesting sentence, and I am long I am a very interesting sentence, and I am long } \\
            \multirow{3}{*}{ Essential Steps } & Step & System response \\
            & 1. I am a very interesting sentence & I am a very interesting sentence \\
            & 2. I am a very interesting sentence & I am a very interesting sentence \\
        \end{tabularx} 
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

I want the result of my multicolumns, but with use of a new columntype.
I will use this columntype in more than one tabularx.
I tried to create, a dynamic columtype for `n` columns, but a columntype for 2 columns, as i tried with my columntype `TowX` would be sufficent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not define a multicolumn specification via `\newcolumntype` however you can define a command to do this

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\zz[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{>{\hsize=%
\dimexpr\numexpr#1\relax\hsize+
\numexpr#1*2-2\relax\tabcolsep+
\numexpr#1-1\relax\arrayrulewidth
\relax}X}}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Example}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXX}       
            Name & \zz{2}{Test} \\
            Target & \zz{2}{ I am a very interesting sentence, and I am long I am a very interesting sentence, and I am long } \\
            \multirow{3}{*}{ Essential Steps } & Step & System response \\
            & 1. I am a very interesting sentence & I am a very interesting sentence \\
            & 2. I am a very interesting sentence & I am a very interesting sentence \\
        \end{tabularx} 
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't it be, a `+` after tabcolsep? And does `\numexpr` and `\relax` leads a calculation of the enclosed part, or what excactly does this?

Comment: @duichwer yes should be a `+` sorry. `\numexpr` is the same as `\dimexpr` that you had already used, but for integer expressions rather than dimension expressions.

Answer (score 1):

With a possible page break between tabular lines:

```
\documentclass[captions=tableabove]{scrbook}
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{lXX | }       
\caption{Example}\\
Name & \multicolumn{2}{Y|}{Test} \\
Target & \multicolumn{2}{Y|}{ I am a very 
    interesting sentence, and I 
    am 
    long I am a 
    very 
    interesting sentence, and I am long } \\
\multirow{3}{*}{ Essential Steps } & Step & System response \\
        & 1. I am a very interesting sentence & I am a very interesting sentence \\
        & 2. I am a very interesting sentence & I am a very interesting sentence \\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that works but `Y` can then only be used with `\multicolumn{2}` it can not be used with `\multicolumn{3}`

Comment: sure, that's obvious! However, using an argument for `\newcolumntype` is also possible!