# How can write a long text as cell colspaned content of a table?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a problem with creating the following table:
[image]

I wrote this code which creates the following table instead of the one above.

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{4}{Y|}}
    \hline

    Identificador & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{RN001} \cline{2-4} \hline
    
    Nome & Teste & OK & Olá \\   \cline{1-4}

    Identificador & \multicolumn{3}{ p{\dimexpr0.93\linewidth+3\tabcolsep} }{ 
    Sempre que uma pessoa se dirigir ao departamento de expedição para solicitar uma mercadoria esta pessoa deve se identificar com seu documento de identidade. O profissional do departamento de expedição deve certificar-se que o documento é válido. Para validar o documento fornecido pela pessoa o número do documento deverá ser validado no sistema da Secretaria de Segurança Pública do Estado de São Paulo, através de funcionalidade correspondente no módulo de controle de expedição. Se o documento não tiver como órgão emissor SSP-SP, não precisará ser validado, mas deverá ser microfilmado e ter uma cópia armazenada no sistema, através de funcionalidade específica.
    } \cline{2-4} \hline
    % \cline{3-4}
    
    % \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{teste} & S & M     \\ \cline{1-4}
    
    % \multirow{3}{=}{SOC}
    
    % & S & S & Z    \\ \cline{2-4}
    % & M & M & Z     \\ \cline{2-4}
    % & H & M & Z     \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

How can I fixed the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the `tabularray` package. It makes merging cells very easy.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236155/82917.

Answer (score 3):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236156/82917 explains how to handle the `X` columns. Of course, since you need it often I would define an ad-hoc command for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\spanthreecols}{\multicolumn{3}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr3\hsize+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}X|}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}%
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\columncolor{lightgray}\bfseries\raggedright}X|X|X|X|}
\hline
Identificador & \spanthreecols{RN0001} \\
\hline
Nome & \spanthreecols{Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.}\\
\hline
Data de criação & 31/01/2016 & \cellcolor{lightgray}\bfseries Autor & Nagarjuna \\
\hline
Descrição & \spanthreecols{Text text bla bla lorem ipsum text text bla bla lorem ipsum 
                           text bla bla lorem ipsum.\par
                           Text text bla bla lorem ipsum text text text.
             }\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{
  width=\linewidth, 
  colspec={*{4}{X[l,m]}}, hlines={gray!50}, vlines={gray!50},
  hspan=minimal, 
  rowsep=6pt,
  column{1,3}={lightgray!50, font=\bfseries}
  }
  Identificador & \SetCell[c=3]{l} RN001&& \\
  Nome &  \SetCell[c=3]{l} Some text on three columns text text text text text text text text text text&&\\
  Módulo & \SetCell[c=3]{l} Text text text &&\\
  Data de criação & 31/01/2016 & Autor & Nagarjuna\\
  Data última alteração & N/A & Autor & N/A\\
  Versão & 1 & Dependência & RFoogg \\   
  Identificador & \SetCell[c=3]{l} Sempre que uma pessoa se dirigir ao departamento de expedição para solicitar uma mercadoria esta pessoa deve se identificar com seu documento de identidade. O profissional do departamento de expedição deve certificar-se que o documento é válido. Para validar o documento fornecido pela pessoa o número do documento deverá ser validado no sistema da Secretaria de Segurança Pública do Estado de São Paulo, através de funcionalidade correspondente no módulo de controle de expedição. Se o documento não tiver como órgão emissor SSP-SP, não precisará ser validado, mas deverá ser microfilmado e ter uma cópia armazenada no sistema, através de funcionalidade específica. &&
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]